# how to use group_by in r to solve my problem. is there any other soln?

Tags: r, dplyr

DATA LOOKS LIKE THIS IN A DATAFRAME

```r
DATE       EXPIRY_Date  strikeprice  daystoexpiry  closeprice
1/1/2019   1/7/2019      1500           6             50
1/1/2019   1/7/2019      1600           6             25
1/1/2019   1/7/2019      1700           6             20
1/1/2019   1/14/2019      1500          13            75
1/1/2019   1/14/2019      1600          13            50
1/1/2019   1/14/2019      1700          13            35
1/1/2019   1/14/2019      1800          13            25
1/1/2019   1/14/2019      1900          13            15
1/1/2019   1/21/2019      1500          20            100
1/1/2019   1/21/2019      1600          20            70
1/1/2019   1/28/2019      1500          27            130
1/1/2019   1/28/2019      1600          27            85
1/1/2019   1/28/2019      1700          27            70
1/2/2019   1/7/2019      1500           5             40
1/2/2019   1/7/2019      1600           5             16
1/2/2019   1/7/2019      1700           5             10
1/2/2019   1/14/2019     1500           12            50
1/2/2019   1/14/2019     1600           12            50
1/2/2019   1/14/2019     1700           12            50
1/2/2019   1/21/2019     1500           19            75
1/2/2019   1/21/2019     1600           19            60
1/2/2019   1/21/2019     1700           19            40
1/2/2019   1/282019      1500           26            50
```

For every date there are different daystoexpiry data.
i want dATA to be arranged in a such a fashion that for every date lowest dte  row goes into one dataframe. so that i will have one dataframe of all dates  which has lowest dte for that date.
then i want another dataframe which will have data of all dates  with  second lowest dte  and 3rd lowest dte is dataframe

output sud look like this

```r
DATE       EXPIRY_Date  strikeprice  daystoexpiry  closeprice
1/1/2019   1/7/2019      1500           6             50
1/1/2019   1/7/2019      1600           6             25
1/1/2019   1/7/2019      1700           6             20
1/2/2019   1/7/2019      1500           5             40
1/2/2019   1/7/2019      1600           5             16
1/2/2019   1/7/2019      1700           5             10
```

another output datafrmae

```r
DATE       EXPIRY_Date  strikeprice  daystoexpiry  closeprice
1/1/2019   1/14/2019      1500          13            75
1/1/2019   1/14/2019      1600          13            50
1/1/2019   1/14/2019      1700          13            35
1/1/2019   1/14/2019      1800          13            25
1/1/2019   1/14/2019      1900          13            15
1/2/2019   1/14/2019      1500          12            50
1/2/2019   1/14/2019      1600          12            50
1/2/2019   1/14/2019      1700          12            50
```

3rd datafrmae output

```r
DATE       EXPIRY_Date  strikeprice  daystoexpiry  closeprice
1/1/2019   1/21/2019      1500          20            100
1/1/2019   1/21/2019      1600          20            70
1/2/2019   1/21/2019      1500          19            75
1/2/2019   1/21/2019      1600          19            60
1/2/2019   1/21/2019      1700          19            40
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to group by `DATE` and find the min of `daystoexpiry`. Using package `dplyr` gives you

```r
# minimum
df %>%
  group_by(DATE) %>%
  filter(daystoexpiry == min(daystoexpiry))

# second lowest
df %>%
  group_by(DATE) %>%
  filter(daystoexpiry == sort(unique(daystoexpiry))[2])

# third lowest
df %>%
  group_by(DATE) %>%
  filter(daystoexpiry == sort(unique(daystoexpiry))[3])
```